# Error in compiling 'if' statement

Tags: lua

I run a small Lua chunk as an event loop, calling luaL_loadstring() to load it.
Note that I have two C functions in these samples; the function logmsg() outputs its string argument to a log file, and the function getevt() waits until an event is ready to be passed to the chunk and returns a integer event ID when an event occurs.

When I load this chunk:

```
logmsg( 'Entering evt loop' )
while true do
    local evt
    evt = getevt()
    logmsg( 'Got event '..evt )
    if evt == 73 then
        logmsg( "Event equal to 73" )
    end
end
logmsg( "Exited evt loop" )
```

the load succeeds and when I run it I get exactly the expected output.

But if I try to change the condition in the 'if' statement like this:

```
logmsg( 'Entering evt loop' )
while true do
    local evt
    evt = getevt()
    logmsg( 'Got event '..evt )
    if evt < 73 then
        logmsg( "Event less than 73" )
    elseif evt > 73 then
        logmsg( "Event greater than 73" )
    else
        logmsg( "Event equal to 73" )
    end
end
logmsg( "Exited evt loop" )
```

then the load fails, and returns error code 3 with error string

> [string "logmsg( 'Entering evt loop' ) ..."]:6: 'then' expected near ';'

How is this possible? There's not even a ';' character in the chunk. Is it possible that if my editor puts CR instead of CR+LF, it confuses the compiler?

Comment: You can check if cr/cr+lf is the issue by running `unix2dos` or a similar program on the source code.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Thanks, I can deal with that. But do you think the code should be valid otherwise? That's my main concern...

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me from the code itself.  I'm thinking the issue may be from code that comes *before* your snippet like an unclosed quote.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: The thing is, that's not just a snippet--it's the entire chunk that is executed. I think I'm going to just rewrite it with my usual editor and see if the error goes away. It's really weird. Thanks again for looking it over.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: FYI, I found the problem, posted it as an answer to my own question. Nothing wrong with the Lua code--but the code was being modified before being passed into the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The chunk is being passed in through an XML interface, and it seems that "<" is being converted to "&lt;" in the process. That explains the mysterious error message, and the ";" that wasn't there in the original code. I only found this by doing a raw buffer dump of the string being passed in before passing it on to luaL_loadstring(). Wow. Never expected that.